# Can we add cc or bcc for Task?

Tags: standard-objects

I know that salesforce we send email to assignee when ever we create a task for them.But is there possibilities to include cc/bcc to other person in this email?

Answer (score 0):

You can add BCC. Go to Setup > BCC email compliance and provide the email I'd and enable it.

Comment: this one will apply to the whole org email right?Can we customize it on certain object then it will send different email?

Comment: Yes ! this will apply to whole org and you can not customize it. You can look into this. https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000181643&language=en_US